# Strange Python behavior from inappropriate usage of 'is not' comparison?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I (incorrectly?) used 'is not' in a comparison and found this curious behavior:

```
>>> a = 256
>>> b = int('256')
>>> c = 300
>>> d = int('300')
>>>
>>> a is not b
False
>>> c is not d
True
```

Obviously I should have used:

```
>>> a != b
False
>>> c != d
False
```

But it worked for a long time due to small-valued test-cases until I happened to
use a number of 495.

If this is invalid syntax, then why?  And shouldn't I at least get a warning?

Comment: Here is your warning: "Don't use identity checking when you mean equality checking!"

Comment: @Paul: amen! And if I may expand with an imaginary example: “Never use `.is_strawberry()` when you want to use `.is_red()`.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"is" is not a check of equality of value, but a check that two variables point to the same instance of an object.

`int`s and `string`s are confusing for this as `is` and `==` can happen to give the same result due to how the internals of the language work.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the down vote: if my answer is inaccurate, I'd quite like to know why so I don't make the same mistakes again...

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get an answer to your previous comment; I believe it should be obligatory to add a comment for every downvote, but who am I? So I just upvoted you.

Answer (score 5):

For small numbers, Python is reusing the object instances, but for larger numbers, it creates new instances for them.

See this:

```
>>> a=256
>>> b=int('256')
>>> c=300       
>>> d=int('300')

>>> id(a)
158013588
>>> id(b)
158013588
>>> id(c)
158151472
>>> id(d)
158151436
```

which is exactly why `a` is `b`, but `c` *isn't* `d`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use *is [not]* to compare integers; use == and != instead.  Even though *is* works in current CPython for small numbers due to an optimization, it's unreliable and semantically wrong.  The syntax itself is valid, but the benefits of a warning (which would have to be checked on every use of *is* and could be problematic with subclasses of int) are presumably not worth the trouble.

This is covered elsewhere on SO, but I didn't find it just now.

Comment: +1 The language does not guarantee `is` will work for small numbers. An implementation is free to not make this optimisation

Comment: Yes, that's a point worth emphasizing.  (However, I don't know how IronPython or Jython currently work.)

Answer (score 0):

**Int is an object in python**, and python caches small integer between [-5,256] by default, so where you use **int** in [-5,256], they are identical.

```
a = 256
b = 256

a is b # True
```

If you declare two integers not in [-5,256], python will create two objects which are not the same(though they have the same value).

```
a = 257
b = 257

a is b # False
```

In your case, using `!=` instead to compare the value is the right way.

```
a = 257
b = 257

a != b # False
```

Answer (score -1):

For more understanding why this occurs take a look to **Python-2.6.5/Objects/intobject.c:78:small_ints** array and **Python-2.6.5/Objects/intobject.c:1292:_PyInt_Init** function in python sources.

Also similar thing occurs with lists:

```
>>> a = [12]
>>> id_a = id(a)
>>> del(a)
>>> id([1,2,34]) == id_a
True
>>>
```

Removed lists are not destroyed. They are reused

Comment: id's in general are reused, whether they point to lists or not.  That is why there is no reliable id->object mapping capability. But for this to happen, the first object to have that id must be deleted (as you did in `del a`). Reusing id's is not the same as the low-value-integer optimization that the OP asked about.  In the OP's case, there was no deletion of the first int before the comparison of id's.

Comment: >id's in general are reused
Yes.
> Reusing id's is not the same as the low-value-integer optimization that the OP asked about.
No, it is the same. See for usage of Python-2.6.5/Objects/listobject.c:97:free_list array

Comment: my point was that your example shows how an id gets reused when one object gets deleted and another different object gets created and recycles the same id. The OP is being confused by an implementation-dependent optimization in which multiple different names for simple immutable types get bound to the same object behind the scenes, but all the names are "alive" at the same time - none of them have been "del"ed.  In fact, for this to work, the items a) must be equal, and b) must be immutable.  You describe a different, but equally tricky, behavior, which can apply to any object type.